# Gstreamer artifacts at 160x120

Tags: raspberry-pi, streaming, video-streaming, webcam, gstreamer

I am novice in gstreamer. I have streaming platform from Raspberry pi to Computer. I have problem with gstreamer when I change the input frame size to 160x120 (there are no problems with frame sizes 320x240, 640x480).

I am using gstreamer in Raspberry pi with input as raw video from Logitech C920 to stream to computer. The script at source side (raspberry pi) is:

```
#!/bin/bash

WIDTH=160
HEIGHT=120

ip=192.168.0.150

v4l2-ctl --set-fmt-video=width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,pixelformat=1
v4l2-ctl -i 1

gst-launch-1.0 -v \
rtpbin name=rtpbin v4l2 device=/dev/video0 \
! video/x-raw,width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,framerate=25/1 \
! queue \
! omxh264enc target-bitrate=900000 control-rate=3 \
! "video/x-h264,profile=high" \
! h264parse \
! queue max-size-bytes=10000000 \
! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 \
! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 \
! udpsink port=5000 host=$ip ts-offset=0 name=vrtpsink rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 \
! udpsink port=5001 host=$ip sync=false async=false name=vrtcpsink udpsrc port=5005 name=vrtpsrc \
! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

The video sink is at windows. It runs with following command.

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:4:4, depth=(string)8, width=(string)320, height=(string)240, colorimetry=(string)SMPTE240M, ssrc=(uint)1825678493, payload=(int)96, clock-base=(uint)4068866987, seqnum-base=(uint)24582" port=5000 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin !queue! autovideosink
```

I get video like one this one with close to bottom half with artifacts.

[image]

Video at 320x240 however has no artifacts as you can see below.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: well you defined caps with `width=(string)320, height=(string)240` .. that may be the problem at receiving side

Comment: changing those parameters at receiving side did not help.

Comment: Sometimes there are GStreamer elements that choke on content that is not divisible by 16.  Just as a test, could you try adding scaling the 160x120 content to 320x240 and then stream it, and see if there are still artifacts?  Then we'd know it's an encoder/decoder issue.

Comment: Also I'd simplify your decoding pipeline as it has a lot of very specific info in it.  This is the caps we use:  `application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,encoding-name=H264'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like mpr suggested, the problem is with frame size 160x120 is not divisible by 16. Fixing it would fix the problem